# SharePoint: CQWP display most recent list item (based on Date) for items with same Title

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, cqwp, content-query-rollup

I have a content query webpart on a page in SharePoint 2010 that is pulling information from a custom list residing in the same site. The purpose of this list is to store the dates (start time, end time) for upcoming training sessions.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish: I would like my CQWP to provide a list of training sessions, BUT only display the most recent training session. For example, a training session titled (Basic HTML Training) may be given 10 times. I need the CQWP to hide every Basic HTML Training session besides the most recent one. At the same time, I have many other classes with many training sessions. These other classes need to be presented the same way. **So classes need to be 'grouped' somehow based on their title column, and then each 'group' should only display the most recent training session based on the date column.**

I am not sure how to accomplish this.

**EXAMPLE: If the following items are in a list:**

Training 1
1/10/12

Training 1
1/15/12

Training 1
1/20/12

Training 2
1/15/12

Training 2
1/20/12

Training 2
1/25/12

**The webpart should display:**

Training 1
1/20/12

Training 2
1/25/12

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [custom XSL to CQWP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557.aspx) and then use [grouping](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html) and datetime checks in XSL to display the results.